# What is the anatomy of an ELF file for JIT compiler?

Tags: x86, compiler-construction, elf, jit

I would like to build a program that can expand with new code at runtime (JIT compilation). Wondering, where do I put this new code in an [ELF file](https://github.com/mewmew/dissection)? Do I put it in the `.text` section somehow, or the `.data` section? How does this generally work?

Comment: If it's just-in-time, it happens while the program is running. So it has nothing to do with any file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but for a regular JIT compiler, you don't write anything into a file. You write machine code into memory (just the code - no ELF headers or anything like that) and then you jump into it.

Comment: You put new code in new memory pages you allocate with malloc. 
 (Or really with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC)`.  Or flip them from R+W to R+X once you're done generating code into them, for systems that enforce W^X).  Also related: [Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947302)