# LEA setting RAX to wrong function address

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, machine-code

I have this code that is supposed to insert the address of my function into memory by using LEA and then Calling it but when I do this it insert the correct function address using LEA but something completely different. How would I change the code down below to lea rax to the correct function?

```
BYTE orig[] = { 0x48, 0x8D, 0x04, 0x25 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xD0 };
BYTE shell_code[] = { 0x48, 0x8D, 0x04, 0x25 }; //lea rax

memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)orig), &shell_code, sizeof(shell_code));
uintptr_t hook_address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(kernel_function_address);
memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)orig + sizeof(shell_code)), &hook_address, sizeof(void*));
```

This is the output:
[image: Output]

But the function address should be something more similar to:
[image: this]

I would appreciate any help possible, thank you!

Comment: If you don't want an absolute `[disp32]` addressing mode, don't use one.  Perhaps you want a `mov reg, imm64` instruction so you can fill in a 64-bit absolute address?  (a `void*` / `uintptr_t`)

Comment: @PeterCordes I would've used `mov` but for this project I can't so I thought `LEA` would be a good alternative

Comment: LEA doesn't have a form that can take a 64-bit absolute immediate, so no, it isn't.  If it's in range for a `rel32`, you could use a RIP-relative addressing mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes how could I use RIP-relative addressing in this situation?

Comment: By calculating `hook_address - (orig + 7)` and copying that int32_t into the rel32, if the displacement doesn't overflow an `int32_t`.  (i.e. if `(int32_t)x == x`, for a `ptrdiff_t x`).  Exactly like you'd [calculate a `call rel32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly), but for the end of a 7-byte `lea rax, [RIP+rel32]`.  Semi-related: [Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947302)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, but I seem to have a problem when calculating the first bit. I get the error that `expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum typ` so I can't add 7 to the entire orig. I'm sorry if I'm being annoying but I would really appreciate help, thank you!